# "read"-ing string data into haskell "data" types

Tags: haskell, types

Thanks to [this excellent tutorial](http://lisperati.com/haskell/hasktut.pdf), I know how to read a string (in this case read from a file at `people.txt` directly into a type synonym:

```
type Person = [Int]
```

like this:

```
people_text <- readFile "people.txt"
let people :: [Person]
    people = read people_text
```

What I want to do is use a datatype (instead of a type synonym).

Any pointers on what I am missing here? I thought I would be able to read string-data directly into a `Person` -  defined like this (credit to learnyouahaskell.com)

```
data Person = Person String String Int Float String String deriving (Show)
```

When I try the obvious

```
 txt <- readFile "t.txt" (this works OK)
```

with `t.txt` containing

```
"Buddy" "Finklestein" 43 184.2 "526-2928" "Chocolate"
```

I get this error:

> No instance for `(Read Person)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, you need to derive `Read` for your type.

You can think of `read` and `show` as being opposites, and a sort of poor man's serialization. `show` lets you convert to `String`, `read` converts from `String`, and in most cases the `String` produced should also be valid Haskell code that, when compiled, produces the same value that `read` gives you.

On that note, the contents of your file aren't going to work, because that's not the format used by the default implementations of `read` and `show`, i.e. the implementations you get by putting `Read` and `Show` in the `deriving` clause.

For example, given this:

```
data Person = Person String String Int Float String String deriving (Read, Show)

buddy = Person "Buddy" "Finklestein" 43 184.2 "526-2928" "Chocolate"
```

Then in GHCi, we get:

```
> show buddy
"Person \"Buddy\" \"Finklestein\" 43 184.2 \"526-2928\" \"Chocolate\""
```

The quotes are escaped because that's a `String` value. In the file, it would look like this:

```
Person "Buddy" "Finklestein" 43 184.2 "526-2928" "Chocolate"
```

Which you'll note is the same as the original definition in the source file.

Answer (score 9):

Just add `Read` to the deriving

```
 data Person = Person String String Int Float String String deriving (Show, Read)
```

Comment: adding Read did the trick. I also had to do this to "read" my Person :   xx<- readFile "t.txt" . . ..  then  . . . let myperson = read xx::Person (without the ::Person at the end it was causing an error). Prolly "obvious' to anyone steeped in Haskell, but not (yet) to me

Comment: @camccann's answer is good and more comprehensive. It really deserves more upvotes.

Comment: SO voting behaviors are weird, but predictable. Your answer was first, simple, and correct, so got early upvotes (including from me). I answered several minutes later, and about 30min later it was accepted. Likely voters tend to hit questions a lot within the first 5-10min, then a slow stream until an answer is accepted, after which the question is mostly ignored. For simple questions like this, being fast and correct gets more upvotes than being detailed.

Comment: Actually, the best rep-building strategy is a quick-draw minimally correct answer, edited to add extra detail while collecting early upvotes. But at this point I'm mostly here to be informative, since I have enough rep for most extra privileges, and my ranking on the all-time Haskell high-score chart is... *very* unlikely to improve. So, it's kind of you to say that about my answer and I appreciate the sentiment, but I don't mind. :)

Answer (score 1):

"Read" is a typeclass, which means that it makes sense to have a function `read :: String -> Person`.  You can add "read" to the deriving statement, which will automatically generate something sensible for that `read` function.  Note that it would actually require putting "Person" before the various fields ("Buddy", etc).

Alternatively, you could define your own read function:

```
instance Read Person where 
  read str = undefined -- add your definition here
```